# What this phrase {$R *.dfm} in the code editor?

Tags: delphi, pascal

What this phrase `{$R *.dfm}` in the code editor?

I tried This :

```
//{$R *.dfm}
```

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Resource_file_(Delphi)

Comment: *I tried This: ...* And then what happened?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll want to keep that in there.  The `$R` directive links a resource file into the EXE.  The `*.dfm` means "the file that has the same filename as this `.pas` file, but with a `.dfm` extension instead."

What it does is makes sure that when the compiler builds the project, that your form data ends up compiled in.  Without this, when your code tries to load up the form, it won't be able to find the form data and it will crash.